# Chef is incapable of installing scipy = MemoryError

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am now getting rather concerned about using chef in low ram env's.

The fact that I cant install scipy for python is quite unreal.  I have to wait for an error..ssh into the server, manually run pip install scipy and rerun chef solo and then sever works.  RAM is 1 gig for the server.

Chef..whats the deal?

```
python_package 'scipy' do
  version '0.18.1'
end


--- 67.205.184.137 [2017-02-21T03:20:22+00:00] ERROR: bash[install_scipy] (forex::worker line 34) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170221-3127-cmg0gp" ----
STDOUT: Collecting scipy==0.18.1
  Downloading scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (40.3MB)
STDERR: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext
--- 67.205.184.137  object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hash
--- 67.205.184.137 es)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_ven
--- 67.205.184.137 dor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 357, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 314, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
    self._close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
    ).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170221-3127-cmg0gp" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170221-3127-cmg0gp" returned 2

--- 67.205.184.137 [2017-02-21T03:20:22+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error isn't coming from Chef, it is coming from pip. There's not really much Chef can do about that. SciPy and NumPy both are very complex libraries with a lot of fancy C and Fortran (yes, really) code to compile to make them work. I would look at building your wheel files on a build machine and then installing from those.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --no-cache-dir <pkgname>`.

For more information, see [Excessive memory use when caching large packages](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2984).